# Can I safely exchange the positions of differently-sized gas range burners?

Tags: stove

I have a Frigidaire Gallery dual fuel range. On the left side, the smaller burner is located in the front and I want the smaller burners in the back. 
Is there any reason why I should not swap the jets and burners?

Comment: Model #FGDS3065PF ?

Comment: Quick check: are the feed pipes the same diameter? If so, that would suggest it's ok.

Comment: yes, that's the one. I have not removed any jets yet.

Answer (score 1):

The gas orfices are sized for the BTU heating of each individual burner. A burner that does not match the required orfice size of that burner may not be able to burn the gas supplied correctly: ie. too much gas, not enough air at max flame.

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue, but you have to swap also the giglers. If you swap only the burners you'll have a big burner that won't lit due to too few gas and a little burner burning too high ruining your pans due to oversized gas flow.